# Error building rabbitmq server

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, amqp

I am building rabbitmq server on ubuntu (2.6.35-28-generic-pae #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 20:43:15 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux)

I am using erlang OPT version otp_src_R14B03. I get following error while building

erlc -I include -o ebin -Wall -v +debug_info -Duse_specs -pa ebin src/rabbit_networking.erl
**src/rabbit_networking.erl:49: type hostname() undefined**
**src/rabbit_networking.erl:71: type ip_port() undefined**

Has anyone seen this kind of error before? any thoughts on how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Erlang R14B03 changed some specs in an incompatible way. So you can't compile RabbitMQ 2.4.1 against Erlang R14B03 without disabling specs (should be harmless, it's more for development).

Options:

- Use Erlang R14B02
- Use RabbitMQ from Mercurial default, where this is fixed
- Compile with "make USE_SPECS=false"

We'll probably push out a new release soon, this is biting a few people.

Edited to add: you may not be aware of our apt repository: http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian.html (works on Ubuntu too). That may be a simpler solution for you.